# Dynamic load assembly, how to specify the abstraction?

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, appdomain

Assuming I have 3 levels of abstraction in different dll, composing my application

- Primitive
- Basic implements Primitive
- Foo implements Basic

And my application load dynamically the Foo (Assembly.Load, Activator...), by default is called the CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve event because he can not find the Basic class implementation so I can enter the correct path to load Basic class.

Based on the operation of my business, my application has to be active in 100% of the time.
But I can occur to alter the implementation of Foo (whether by bug fix or change functionality)
So, what I have to do is change the path the dll (configuration), and the next time this function is called "another" Foo is used.

It has worked very well, but if I have the need to load the other Basic class again (in this case I would recompile Basic and Foo), I gotta restart the application, there is a way to indicate which abstraction is used when I go to instantiate a new Foo?

I know that the assemblies will never be discharged (older versions), but this is not a problem for me.

Comment: Create one process per "version" and communicate via MMF - this way you can have different version active in parallel AND get as an added benefit the ability to shutdown a specific version when it is not used anymore...

Comment: seems like a hard strategy. There is someone who is controlling everything, this stops and starts, runs and returns information, concurrence and other problems this is simple when I have access to different objects, that would be a bigger architecture for managing all such communication and each in a separete process.

Comment: @J.Lennon You are talking about altering the implementation of Foo and then in the next paragraph about loading the other Basic class. Are they the same? Did you meant implementation of Basic? What you are trying to accomplish is vague. More info is needed. Are you implementing a script engine (on-site compilation)? How would you like to revert to another impl of Basic?  Are you using strong-named assemblies? Do you create any AppDomains (tag)? Can multiple impls of Basic coexist?